# IronPython: Unexpected token 'from'

Tags: c#, python, .net, tensorflow, ironpython

i was running python script from .net using IronPython, below is my python script

```
import tensorflow as tf    
print('Tensorflow Imported')
```

below is C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var py = Python.CreateEngine();
            List<string> searchPaths = new List<string>();
            searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib)");
            searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages)");
            py.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
            try
            {
                py.ExecuteFile("script.py");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

below is my output

> Unexpected token 'from'

if i remove import statement then python script executes fine. I tried including `os,sys` all those were imported without any issue. I have installed TensorFlow via pip, when i run above script through python console(v3.5) it works fine.

**Update**: in [TF doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) its written "*TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows*". but official release of IronPython is version 2.7
I was happy to find IronPython on [GitHub](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3), tried building it (i just typed build in console and got freaked out with the [long list](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ltv-5Qws1CpUwi3cerafuvdMntATUb66yyxjMkI6G84/edit?usp=sharing) of error messages it showed! :D
couldn't find pre-compiled binaries

is there any alternative way to import tensorflow in IronPython 2.7 or run Python in .net?

Comment: Without a traceback this is terribly hard to diagnose. Apparently tensorflow uses syntax that IronPython doesn't expect.

Comment: Why are you mixing tensorflow from CPython installation with IronPython interpreter? Try pythonnet from CPython. Tensorflow cannot be installed into IronPython.

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/299

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  sorry for late reply. [here's](https://pastebin.com/bF7w28TJ) the call stack ..it was pretty big & hard to understand what it was saying..

Comment: @denfromufa, i'm new to IronPython. from what i understand, i knew that we cannot install TensorFlow in IronPython, so i pointed installed library's directory in `searchPath`. my goal is to run python within .net.  is ther any alternative way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the link I gave above?

Comment: updated question..i didn't know about PythonNet, trying it now. Thank you very much..

Comment: @denfromufa, i tried PythonNet. program is crashing as described [here](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/446)

Comment: Well, you need to learn how to use at least pip to install packages from PyPI. See my answer in your linked GitHub issue.

Comment: please check the new comment in Pythonnet Github issue, also is possible can you post detailed answer (possible solution for my issue) here?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prakash - as you found in the documentation, TensorFlow requires Python 3.5 or 3.6 when running on Windows.  It won't run in IronPython 2.7.

One user on GitHub successfully (with a lot of work and in a not-easy-to-do) way [got TF running on Windows under Python2.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13464), and you might be able to build on their work, but it's not exactly the solution you were looking for for IronPython.  My best suggestion is to go with 3.5 or 3.6.

Comment: I am just import `import os` still I am getting the same error,
my_py.py
`import sys
 sys.path.append("C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib")
 import os
 #import pandas
 print (os.getcwd())
 import string
 print ("Hi")`